# How to correctly and consistently typeset proofs with implications

Tags: spacing, enumerate, ntheorem

I want to typeset proofs that show equivalence of several (numbered) statements. Is there any consistent and nice way to typeset proofs like that, when I want to label the "subproofs" of one statement implying the other with "(x) -> (y)"? I included a minimal working example of what I want it to look like, except for the labels being written on the margin.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{  
listparindent=\parindent,
parsep=0pt,
}
\usepackage[thmmarks, hyperref, amsthm]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{mathtools, dsfont}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\parbox{\linewidth -2\fboxsep -2\fboxrule}{%
\begin{proof} This should become the proof of Morera's theorem.
\begin{enumerate}
\item[(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii):] This implication is trivial.
\item[(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iii):] 
\begin{align*}
F \in \mathcal{O}( D(z,r) ) : F' = f|_{D(z,r)}  &\overset{2.2.4}{\Longrightarrow} f|_{D(z,r)} \in \mathcal{O}(D(z,r)) \\                                                                                    &\Longrightarrow f \in \mathcal{O}(\Omega).
\end{align*}
\item[(iii) $\Rightarrow$ (iv):] Goursat's theorem (Theorem 2.17).
\item[(iv) $\Rightarrow$ (i):] As in theorem 2.19 we see, that on $D(z,r)$  
\[
F : D(z,r) \longrightarrow \mathds{C} \quad , \quad w \mapsto \int_{\gamma_{z \to w}} f(\zeta) \mathop{d\zeta}
\]
is a holomorphic antiderivative to $f$ on $D(z,r)$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about just adding `leftmargin=63pt,` to your `\setlist`?

Comment: If there was another way, I guess I would prefer that. 63pt leftmargin for all enumerations in the document would be too much. I ment consistent as in proofs, not necessarily throughout the entire document. But thanks for the effort, really!

Comment: Alternately, ditch the `leftindent` specifier and add `itemindent=36pt,` to the `\setlist`.  In both alternatives, the specifier may be added as an optional argument to the `enumerate` list rather than in the `\setlist`, if each proof/list must be different.

Comment: I find that no list is necessary: just start the paragraph with `(i)$\implies$(ii)` and let it go.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the comment of the OP, I think the best alternative is to employ the `itemindent=...` optional argument to each particular `enumerate` list requiring a tweak.  That way, the global indent of lists is not affected (if one used the `\setlist`, instead), and the indent of subsequent lines in each `\item` is also not affected (if one used the `leftmargin=` approach, instead).

Of course, this is not as simple as egreg's suggestion of ditching the `\item` specifier altogether; however, that approach provides no leftward offset or right-alignment for the implications.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{  
listparindent=\parindent,
parsep=0pt,
}
\usepackage[thmmarks, hyperref, amsthm]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{mathtools, dsfont}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\parbox{\linewidth -2\fboxsep -2\fboxrule}{%
\begin{proof} This should become the proof of Morera's theorem.
\begin{enumerate}[itemindent=36pt]
\item[(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii):] This implication is trivial.
\item[(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iii):] 
\begin{align*}
F \in \mathcal{O}( D(z,r) ) : F' = f|_{D(z,r)}  &\overset{2.2.4}{\Longrightarrow} f|_{D(z,r)} \in \mathcal{O}(D(z,r)) \\                                                                                    &\Longrightarrow f \in \mathcal{O}(\Omega).
\end{align*}
\item[(iii) $\Rightarrow$ (iv):] Goursat's theorem (Theorem 2.17).
\item[(iv) $\Rightarrow$ (i):] As in theorem 2.19 we see, that on $D(z,r)$  

\[
F : D(z,r) \longrightarrow \mathds{C} \quad , \quad w \mapsto \int_{\gamma_{z \to w}} f(\zeta) \mathop{d\zeta}
\]

is a holomorphic antiderivative to $f$ on $D(z,r)$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
}}

\end{document}
```

[image]